# Client Server Assembly Missing? Db4Objects 7.4

Tags: .net-3.5, db4o

I have downloaded the current version of [Db4Objects](http://developer.db4o.com/files/folders/db4o_74/default.aspx) (7.4) and installed it. It appears to be missing the Client Server assembly Db4objects.Db4o.CS.dll

Does anyone know if Client Server has changed with this version? If it has, does anyone have some details about creating a simple Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it buried in the documention. It has indeed changed....

Page 1140 (of 1318) has the details of creating a DB server.